# Drop down menu alignment

Tags: html, css, menu

can somebody please take a look at my code [JSFiddle][1] and tell me whats missing because there's a problem if you hover over Contact. You will see the difference if you compare it with Services or References, DDM is not the same.

Don't mind about the missing logo(top-left).

Thank you for your time and answer.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jn6D3/2/
```

Comment: i clear your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn6D3/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some CSS edits that fix the problem :); add these to your existing css.

```
nav ul li{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
nav ul ul{
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
nav ul ul li a{
    display: block;
}
.box{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Enjoy!